# Error: Invalid content was found starting with element 'X'. One of '{X}' is expected

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate a simple XML using a simple XSD, but always get this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'linux'. One of '{linux}' is expected.
```

Why? The tag 'linux' is found and is one of {linux}!

java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream xml = new FileInputStream("data/test.xml");
        InputStream xsd = new FileInputStream("data/test.xsd");

        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));

        log.info("OK!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(":(");
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

data/test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<so xmlns="http://test/">
    <linux>
        <debian>true</debian>
        <fedora>true</fedora>
    </linux>
</so>
```

data/test.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://test/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="so">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="linux">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi Dudytz, I validated your XML, but the XSD is incorrect, that's why it doesn't validate.

Comment: What is incorrect? The error message refers to the "linux" tag, but the tag is the first element in sequence of complexType "so".

Comment: Update: I am using JDK 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the schema does not specify `elementFormDefault="qualified"`, the local element declaration of element "linux" is declaring an element in no namespace, but the instance has a linux element in namespace `"http://test/"`. The error message is confusing because it fails to make clear that the problem is with the namespace.

Comment: Wow! Yes, it is. Thanks Michael. The error message is very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Dudytz, your `<xs:any />` is not correct. The document cannot be validated, because the validator needs to be instructed how to validate the document. If you don't want that, you can specifiy for the `<xs:any>` a processContents attribute. If you set this to "lax" or "skip", it will work.

In short: replace `<xs:any>` with `<xs:any processContents="lax" />`

**Update**: We have changed your XSD to a working version:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://test/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test/">
<xs:element name="so">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>           
            <xs:element ref="linux"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="linux">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Erik, thanks for your reply. I have been tried to replace <xs:any> to <xs:any processContents="lax" /> and after with <xs:any processContents="skip" /> but I give the same error.

Comment: I know. Please check the updated answer, I think that will work. At least it works in XMLSpy ;)

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Visually, this is the same version of XSD but with 'linux' element as a REF and not a local anonymous type. Is a Java bug LoL?

Comment: No, it's no a Java bug. It's (apparently) how XSD work. I had the same issue in XMLSpy, which is not Java.

Comment: Glad it's working btw. Could you accept it, so others might benefit from it in the future?

Comment: This answer has been accepted but it NOT the explanation of the problem. See my answer.